PyTorch: Different DataLoader batch sizes yield very different losses
I’m using this approximation example for a sin wave as basis to learning approximation. I’m new to PyTorch… Why do different BATCH_SIZE values significantly change results?
Batch size 512:

Batch size 10000 (all data points):

I am posting the code below but first I’ll explain the changes I made from the original:

All random seeds are static, disabled shuffling:

Learning rate changed to 1e-4, X size changed to 10**4 and changed MAX_EPOCH to 20.

Added a plot to chart the approximation for all values in the range of X, to show the difference


Full code is below…
Thanks!
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from torch import nn, optim
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
LR = 1e-4
MAX_EPOCH = 20
BATCH_SIZE = 10**4

class SineApproximator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SineApproximator, self).__init__()
        self.regressor = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 1024),
                                       nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                                       nn.Linear(1024, 1024),
                                       nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                                       nn.Linear(1024, 1))
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.regressor(x)
        return output


torch.manual_seed(41)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(41)
np.random.seed(41)

X = np.random.rand(10**4) * 2 * np.pi
y = np.sin(X)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = map(torch.tensor, train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, random_state=41))
train_dataloader = DataLoader(TensorDataset(X_train.unsqueeze(1), y_train.unsqueeze(1)), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                              pin_memory=True, shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(TensorDataset(X_val.unsqueeze(1), y_val.unsqueeze(1)), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                            pin_memory=True, shuffle=True)

model = SineApproximator().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LR)
criterion = nn.MSELoss(reduction="mean")

train_loss_list = list()
val_loss_list = list()
for epoch in range(MAX_EPOCH):
    print("epoch %d / %d" % (epoch + 1, MAX_EPOCH))
    model.train()
    # training loop
    temp_loss_list = list()
    for X_train, y_train in train_dataloader:
        X_train = X_train.type(torch.float32).to(device)
        y_train = y_train.type(torch.float32).to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        score = model(X_train)
        loss = criterion(input=score, target=y_train)
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        temp_loss_list.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())

    temp_loss_list = list()
    for X_train, y_train in train_dataloader:
        X_train = X_train.type(torch.float32).to(device)
        y_train = y_train.type(torch.float32).to(device)

        score = model(X_train)
        loss = criterion(input=score, target=y_train)

        temp_loss_list.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())

    avg_loss = np.average(temp_loss_list)
    train_loss_list.append(avg_loss)
    print("\ttrain loss: %.5f" % train_loss_list[-1])

# build a np array with all X values between their min and max values at 0.01 intervals, each value in its own array:
model.eval()
X_all = torch.tensor(np.arange(X.min(), X.max(), 0.01)).type(torch.float32).unsqueeze(1).to(device)
y_prediction = model(X_all)
y_prediction = y_prediction.detach().cpu().numpy().flatten()
original = plt.scatter(X, y, s=1)
predicted = plt.scatter(X_all.detach().cpu().numpy(), y_prediction, s=1)
plt.legend((predicted, original), ("Function", "Samples"))
plt.waitforbuttonpress()

Update: based on @karl's advice, I compensated for the low number of update steps in high batch sizes, by increasing epochs, changing them from 20 to 20 * (10000/512) ~= 400 which yielded a similar approximation (same LR):


Batch size changes the number of update steps per epoch. Run the larger batch size for the same number of update steps as the smaller batch size and compare

Can you pleaes clarify: do you mean to simply re-run the same 10000 data points over and over in the same epoch until I reach the same number of updates steps as with the small batch? Doesn't it mean that I keep training on the same data?

I mean run more epochs until you reach the same number of update steps. Literally just increase the MAX_EPOCH value to compensate.

Indeed this helped. I'll attach an image above. I switched to 400 epocs (20 * 10000/512) and am getting a very similar approximation. Thanks!
